# How do I pull CSharpEntityTypeGenerator into the project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, ef-core-3.0

I've seen lots of posts talking about how to subclass `CSharpEntityTypeGenerator` to modify what EF Core writes out.  Visual studio doesn't like that and says to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`.  I've installed v3.1.0-preview1.19506.2.

However, VS still says that it can't find that class and to install the NuGet package.

What's the magic to make this work?

I'm wanting to write a class like this so that `#nullable disable` is added and the `GeneratedCode` attribute is inserted.

```cs
public class EntityTypeGenerator : CSharpEntityTypeGenerator
{
    public EntityTypeGenerator(ICSharpHelper helper) : base(helper) { }

    public override string WriteCode(IEntityType type, string @namespace, bool useDataAnnotations)
    {
        var code = base.WriteCode(type, @namespace, useDataAnnotations);

        var old = "public partial class " + type.Name;
        var updated = "[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode]\n" + old;

        return code.Replace(old, updated).Replace("namespace", "#nullable disable\n\nnamespace");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update the reference in your project file:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <!-- Remove IncludeAssets to allow compiling against the assembly -->
  <!--<IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>-->
</PackageReference>
```

Comment: I had to remove the PrivateAssets as well and then it worked.  Thanks!

Comment:  That allows it to flow into other dependent projects